# sudoers file not working

Tags: linux, redhat, sudo, sssd

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the sudoers file is not working.  Anytime a user tries to login and elevate, they are give the error `<name> is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported`

The sudoers file itself does not seem to be configured incorrectly, here is an example of the configuration

```
## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d (the # here does not mean a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
account1 ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
account2 ALL=(ALL)     NOPASSWD: ALL
%group1     ALL=(ALL)       ALL
Defaults:%group1    !requiretty
```

It is using the same configuration as other servers in the network.  Any thoughts?  I am using RedHat 6.7 with SSSD for authentication.  The machine is joined to a windows domain and utilizing POSIX from Active Directory.

Also, if I do an `id` on my account it shows I am part of `group1`

[@machine ~]$ id
uid=10090() gid=10010(group1) groups=10010(group1)

Comment: Did you edit using visudo and did it give you any warnings?  Aside from missing some Defaults to keep certain environment variables, nothing pops out at me as being incorrect here.

Comment: clear your sssd cache, double check that there arent any erroneous characters that were added from copying the file into sudoers. also verify the file permissions on /etc/sudoers